# Quit an application using AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, exit

Whenever I try to quit an application using AppleScript I get the following error

> An error of type -9874 has occurred.

The AppleScript command which I am using is

```
tell application "app_name"
    quit
end tell
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Are you sure that "app_name" exists ? If it does exist, are you sure that it knows how to respond to AppleEvents (is "AppleEvent-aware") ? Try the following test - launch `Activity Monitor` (in `/Applications/Utilities`) and run this script:

```
tell application "Activity Monitor"
    quit
end tell
```

This works fine for me - if it works OK for you then the problem is probably with your specific application. If it doesn't work for you then you have some kind of system-related problem - try it on a different Mac to verify ?

Comment: Does the basic commands such as open, quit work for an application which is not scriptable?

Comment: All apps are *supposed* to respond to the four required core AppleEvents, but there are no guarantees, at least for Carbon apps, where explicit code is needed to handle even these four events. I'm not sure about Cocoa apps - it may be the there is some default handling built into Cocoa which makes all Cocoa apps at least aware of these events.

Comment: slightly shorter: `tell application "Activity Monitor" to quit"`